# Терминал неадекватно реагирует на команду python manage.py runserver (выдаёт надпись Python, вместо запуска локального сервера)

Tags: python, django, консоль, pycharm

Терминал странно реагирует на команду python manage.py runserver(такая проблема возникла при переносе фала с одного компьютера на другой с помощью флешки(до переноса данных на другой компьютер всё работало нормально[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Возможно не все нужные библиотеки были установлены

Comment: до переноса данных на другой компьютер всё работало нормально

Comment: Нужно добавить информацию. Запускается ли питон сам по себе? Создавали ли вы виртуальное окружение или пользуетесь системным? Добавляли ли django в виртуальное окружение? Покажите вывод `pip freeze`

Comment: Судя по терминалу виртуальное окружение не активировано. Что настроено в Settings | Project ... | Project Interpreter? Можно попробовать запустить `where python` в терминале - что возвращается?

Comment: Если виртуальное окружение лежало внутри проекта, то оно не пережило переноса на новую машину. Из коробки они непереносимы, поскольку содержат символические ссылки на базовый интерпретатор из которого были созданы.

Answer (score 0):

Проверь установлен ли у тебя python, в path в windows должен быть добавлен, если не знаешь, как добавить или где это искать, то вот - https://pythonru.com/baza-znanij/skachat-i-ustanovit-python-na-windows-10